# Initialize JQuery Datepicker with a blank value

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code still sets the field to today's date

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy", changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true, yearRange: '1900:2020', defaultDate: ''
        });

    });

</script>
```

How do I universally configure the field to start as blank?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If the field is showing today's date it's because of how the input field is populated. The datepicker will start with whatever value the html element has, regardless of what that is:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QXhfU/)

If you cannot control the value of the input field through changing markup, but still needs the input field to be reset, you'll have to do this manually:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy", changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true, yearRange: '1900:2020'
    }).val('');
});
```

Comment: I was initializing in my EditorTemplate the date and I forgot I had done that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#start-date-filter").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        yearRange: '-2:+4'
}).val('');
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.