# jquery datepicker set end date value blank

Tags: php, jquery, html

My code:

```
<html>
<head>   
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        onSelect: function(selected){
            $("#datepicker2").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected);
        }
    });

    $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#reset').click(function(){
        $('#datepicker2').datepicker("option", "minDate", null);
    });
});
</script>

<body>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Start Date : </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="startdate" id="datepicker1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>End Date : </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="enddate" id="datepicker2" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Add" />
            <input type="reset" id="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" /> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
```

From above code, refer to below image:
[image]

First, I am going to choose start date is 7 Dec 2015 and end date is 8 Dec 2015, after that I choose the start date is 9 Dec 2015. I want the end date value is blank when I choose the start date is 9 Dec 2015. Is it possible to do it in Jquery? Can someone help me?

Comment: Stackoverflow link [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228931/initialize-jquery-datepicker-with-a-blank-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you script to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        onSelect: function(selected){
            $("#datepicker2").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected);
        }
    });

    $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });


    $("#datepicker1").focusout(function(){
         $('#datepicker2').val('');
    });


    $('#reset').click(function(){
        $('#datepicker2').datepicker("option", "minDate", null);
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fcrt34xo/)