# jquery datepicker get date (part 2)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Cont on [jquery datepicker set end date value blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34129220/jquery-datepicker-set-end-date-value-blank/34131726#34131726)

My code:

```
<html>
<head>   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui-themes-1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        onSelect: function(selected){
            $("#datepicker2").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected);
        }
    });

    $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });

    $("#datepicker1").focusout(function(){
        $('#datepicker2').val('');
    });

    $('#reset').click(function(){
        $('#datepicker2').datepicker("option", "minDate", null);
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Start Date : </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="startdate" id="datepicker1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>End Date : </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="enddate" id="datepicker2" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Add" />
            <input type="reset" id="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" /> 
        </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to get the start date and end date value from text field. After that I want to perform the following:
- start date value is blank => show "You must select start date" message
- end date value is blank => show "You must select end date" message

This is the logic that I tried:

```
var startdate = $('#datepicker1').val(); //start date text field
var enddate = $('#datepicket2').val(); //end date text field

if(startdate == '')
    alert("You must select start date");

if(enddate == '')
    alert("You must select end date");
```

But I didn't know where should I put them in my code. Can someone help me?

Comment: When do you want it to be called?

Comment: sounds like you need a change event

Comment: I think that you should validate the inputs when the user submit the form, right?

Answer (score 1):

You should add a function to call the onclick event of the button "submit":

```
 <td>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Add" onclick="return CheckFields();" />
 <input type="reset" id="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" /> 
</td>
```

and then create a function with that code in it:

```
function CheckFields()
{
  var startdate = $('#datepicker1').val(); //start date text field
  var enddate = $('#datepicket2').val(); //end date text field

  if(startdate == '')
  {
      alert("You must select start date");
      return false;
  }

  if(enddate == '')
  {
      alert("You must select end date");
      return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```